# Get AngularJS inspector to show controller titles?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

In the 'AngularJS' tab in my Chrome inspector, how can I see what the controllers' names are?

This:

[image]

isn't very helpful sometimes

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is detailed enough for SO standards but I don't know what else I could add

Comment: Just for clarification: A scope doesn't have to be associated with a controller. On the other hand several controllers can use the same scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to get to controllers, the best way I have found is to use the performance tab, and it can take you to the html/js where the code lives.

Comment: Hm interesting solution. I'll mark it as correct if I don't get a more direct method by tomorrow